# I have 3 different classes with same method that having return type string ,how can i display all these method by creating one more class

Tags: java, inheritance, hierarchical

I have 3 different classes with same method that having return type string ,how can i display all these method by creating one more class, i have tried to call by creating other class with object

```
public class SuperDepartment {
    public String departmentName() {
        return "Super Department" ;
    }
    public String getTodaysWork() {
        return "No Work as of now" ;
    }
    public String getWorkdeadline() {
        return "Nill" ;
    }
    public String isTodayAHoliday() {
        return "Today is not a holiday" ;
    }

public class AdminDepartment extends SuperDepartment {
public String  departmentName() {
        
        return "Admin department";
        
        
    }
    public String getTodaysWork() {
        return "Complete your document submission";
        
    }
    public String getWorkDeadline() {
        return "Complete by EOD";
    }
    
}

public class HrDepartment extends SuperDepartment {
public String departmentName() {
        return "Hr Department";
    }
    public String getTodaysWork() {
        return "Fill todays worksheet and mark your attendence";
    }
    public String getWorkDeadline() {
        return "Complete by EOD";
    }
    public String doActivity() {
        return "team Lunch";
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. Please try to rephrase your question with a clear problem statement and show whatever code you've tried. To me it just sounds like you need a Main class with a `main()` method where you instantiate the different classes and call the methods on each instance

Comment: Actually i am new in programming, i have created a main class with main method and created an object under HrDepartment class (Mentioned in the cod) and called one method "getTodaysWork" (mentioned ) ,when i run the cod its showing nothing.

Comment: Are you actually printing it (System.out.println())? Please show the code in your main class

Comment: I missed out "System.out.println",i thought it would be printed by calling the method itself, thanks for the advice.